# Dúvida codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

Opa Galera!
Estou começando com php e codeigniter, tenho uma dúvida:
Tenho dois controllers,cada um com funções de crud,porem precisaria que as views de create(formulário) fossem carregadas numa 3ª página juntas,como fazer isso?
(Como se fossem um só formulário, mas na real serão dois),ou uma dica de outro jeito p fazer isso,por favor!!
    Model

```
 <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Eventos_model extends CI_Model
{

    public $table = 'eventos';
    public $id = 'idEvento';
    public $order = 'DESC';






    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }


    function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
    }


    function total_rows($q = NULL) {
        $this->db->like('idEvento', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('nome_evento', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('data_inicio', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('data_fim', $q);
    $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }


    function get_limit_data($limit, $start = 0, $q = NULL) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        $this->db->like('idEvento', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('nome_evento', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('data_inicio', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('data_fim', $q);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }


    function insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);


    }


    function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }


    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }



}
```

Model

```
 <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Categorias_inscricao_model extends CI_Model
{

    public $table = 'categorias_inscricao';
    public $id = 'idCategorias_Inscricao';
    public $order = 'DESC';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function get_all()
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }

    function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->row();
    }


    function total_rows($q = NULL) {
        $this->db->like('idCategorias_Inscricao', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('nome_categoria', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('descricao_categoria', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('valor_categoria', $q);
    $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }


    function get_limit_data($limit, $start = 0, $q = NULL) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        $this->db->like('idCategorias_Inscricao', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('nome_categoria', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('descricao_categoria', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('valor_categoria', $q);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        return $this->db->get($this->table)->result();
    }


    function insert($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }


    function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }


    function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
 <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Eventos extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Eventos_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');



    }

    public function index()
    {
        $q = urldecode($this->input->get('q', TRUE));
        $start = intval($this->input->get('start'));

        if ($q <> '') {
            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'eventos/index.html?q=' . urlencode($q);
            $config['first_url'] = base_url() . 'eventos/index.html?q=' . urlencode($q);
        } else {
            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'eventos/index.html';
            $config['first_url'] = base_url() . 'eventos/index.html';
        }

        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Eventos_model->total_rows($q);
        $eventos = $this->Eventos_model->get_limit_data($config['per_page'], $start, $q);

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data = array(
            'eventos_data' => $eventos,
            'q' => $q,
            'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
            'total_rows' => $config['total_rows'],
            'start' => $start,
        );
        $this->load->view('eventos_list', $data);
    }

    public function read($id) 
    {
        $row = $this->Eventos_model->get_by_id($id);
        if ($row) {
            $data = array(
        'idEvento' => $row->idEvento,
        'nome_evento' => $row->nome_evento,
        'data_inicio' => $row->data_inicio,
        'data_fim' => $row->data_fim,
        );
            $this->load->view('eventos_read', $data);

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('eventos'));
        }
    }

    public function create() 
    {
        $data = array(
            'button' => 'Create',
            'action' => site_url('eventos/create_action'),
        'idEvento' => set_value('idEvento'),
        'nome_evento' => set_value('nome_evento'),
        'data_inicio' => set_value('data_inicio'),
        'data_fim' => set_value('data_fim'),



    );
        $this->load->view('eventos_form', $data);

    }

    public function create_action() 
    {
        $this->_rules();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->create();
        } else {
            $data = array(
        'nome_evento' => $this->input->post('nome_evento',TRUE),
        'data_inicio' => $this->input->post('data_inicio',TRUE),
        'data_fim' => $this->input->post('data_fim',TRUE),

        );

            $this->Eventos_model->insert($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Create Record Success');
            redirect(site_url('template'));
        }
    }

    public function update($id) 
    {
        $row = $this->Eventos_model->get_by_id($id);

        if ($row) {
            $data = array(
                'button' => 'Update',
                'action' => site_url('eventos/update_action'),
        'idEvento' => set_value('idEvento', $row->idEvento),
        'nome_evento' => set_value('nome_evento', $row->nome_evento),
        'data_inicio' => set_value('data_inicio', $row->data_inicio),
        'data_fim' => set_value('data_fim', $row->data_fim),
        );
            $this->load->view('eventos_form', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('eventos'));
        }
    }

    public function update_action() 
    {
        $this->_rules();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->update($this->input->post('idEvento', TRUE));
        } else {
            $data = array(
        'nome_evento' => $this->input->post('nome_evento',TRUE),
        'data_inicio' => $this->input->post('data_inicio',TRUE),
        'data_fim' => $this->input->post('data_fim',TRUE),
        );

            $this->Eventos_model->update($this->input->post('idEvento', TRUE), $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Update Record Success');
            redirect(site_url('eventos'));
        }
    }

    public function delete($id) 
    {
        $row = $this->Eventos_model->get_by_id($id);

        if ($row) {
            $this->Eventos_model->delete($id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Delete Record Success');
            redirect(site_url('eventos'));
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('eventos'));
        }
    }

    public function _rules() 
    {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome_evento', 'nome evento', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_inicio', 'data inicio', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('data_fim', 'data fim', 'trim|required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('idEvento', 'idEvento', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="text-danger">', '</span>');
    }







}
```

Controller

```
  <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Categorias_inscricao extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Categorias_inscricao_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $q = urldecode($this->input->get('q', TRUE));
        $start = intval($this->input->get('start'));

        if ($q <> '') {
            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'categorias_inscricao/index.html?q=' . urlencode($q);
            $config['first_url'] = base_url() . 'categorias_inscricao/index.html?q=' . urlencode($q);
        } else {
            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'categorias_inscricao/index.html';
            $config['first_url'] = base_url() . 'categorias_inscricao/index.html';
        }

        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->total_rows($q);
        $categorias_inscricao = $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->get_limit_data($config['per_page'], $start, $q);

        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data = array(
            'categorias_inscricao_data' => $categorias_inscricao,
            'q' => $q,
            'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
            'total_rows' => $config['total_rows'],
            'start' => $start,
        );
        $this->load->view('categorias_inscricao_list', $data);
    }

    public function read($id) 
    {
        $row = $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->get_by_id($id);
        if ($row) {
            $data = array(
        'idCategorias_Inscricao' => $row->idCategorias_Inscricao,
        'nome_categoria' => $row->nome_categoria,
        'descricao_categoria' => $row->descricao_categoria,
        'valor_categoria' => $row->valor_categoria,
        );
            $this->load->view('categorias_inscricao_read', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('categorias_inscricao'));
        }
    }

    public function create() 
    {
        $data = array(
            'button' => 'Create',
            'action' => site_url('categorias_inscricao/create_action'),
        'idCategorias_Inscricao' => set_value('idCategorias_Inscricao'),
        'nome_categoria' => set_value('nome_categoria'),
        'descricao_categoria' => set_value('descricao_categoria'),
        'valor_categoria' => set_value('valor_categoria'),
    );
        $this->load->view('categorias_inscricao_form', $data);
    }

    public function create_action() 
    {
        $this->_rules();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->create();
        } else {
            $data = array(
        'nome_categoria' => $this->input->post('nome_categoria',TRUE),
        'descricao_categoria' => $this->input->post('descricao_categoria',TRUE),
        'valor_categoria' => $this->input->post('valor_categoria',TRUE),
        );

            $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->insert($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Create Record Success');
            redirect(site_url('categorias_inscricao'));
        }
    }

    public function update($id) 
    {
        $row = $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->get_by_id($id);

        if ($row) {
            $data = array(
                'button' => 'Update',
                'action' => site_url('categorias_inscricao/update_action'),
        'idCategorias_Inscricao' => set_value('idCategorias_Inscricao', $row->idCategorias_Inscricao),
        'nome_categoria' => set_value('nome_categoria', $row->nome_categoria),
        'descricao_categoria' => set_value('descricao_categoria', $row->descricao_categoria),
        'valor_categoria' => set_value('valor_categoria', $row->valor_categoria),
        );
            $this->load->view('categorias_inscricao_form', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('categorias_inscricao'));
        }
    }

    public function update_action() 
    {
        $this->_rules();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->update($this->input->post('idCategorias_Inscricao', TRUE));
        } else {
            $data = array(
        'nome_categoria' => $this->input->post('nome_categoria',TRUE),
        'descricao_categoria' => $this->input->post('descricao_categoria',TRUE),
        'valor_categoria' => $this->input->post('valor_categoria',TRUE),
        );

            $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->update($this->input->post('idCategorias_Inscricao', TRUE), $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Update Record Success');
            redirect(site_url('categorias_inscricao'));
        }
    }

    public function delete($id) 
    {
        $row = $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->get_by_id($id);

        if ($row) {
            $this->Categorias_inscricao_model->delete($id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Delete Record Success');
            redirect(site_url('categorias_inscricao'));
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Record Not Found');
            redirect(site_url('categorias_inscricao'));
        }
    }

    public function _rules() 
    {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome_categoria', 'nome categoria', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricao_categoria', 'descricao categoria', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('valor_categoria', 'valor categoria', 'trim|required|numeric');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('idCategorias_Inscricao', 'idCategorias_Inscricao', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="text-danger">', '</span>');
    }

}
```

Comment: Creio que você deve estar misturando as atribuiçoes. O ideal pra você é colocar os cruds no model. Após isso voce deve criar o controller e chamar a view. Após voce passar pela validacao do form_validation, ai voce deve instanciar os models e usar as respectivas funcoes.

Comment: @IsraelZebulon editei a postagem com os models e controllers p ti ver ,ai tenho duas views de formularios que são os create e preciso chamar elas duas em uma só pagina, como faço?

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi. São 2 views diferentes, cada uma contém um formulário, você quer chamar e exibir as 2 em 1 só documento html, é isso?

Comment: Isso @LFZiron, só que quando tento fazer isso através de $this->load->view('view1');
$this->load->view('view2');
dá erro

Comment: Qual tipo de erro?

Comment: @LFZiron An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: eventos.php

Comment: Isso significa que o sistema não consegue ler  o arquivo application/views/eventos.php.  Você já verificou a existência desse arquivo? Tem mesmo esse nome? O sistema tem permissão de leitura no arquivo?

Comment: voce que carregar a view $this->load->view('categorias_inscricao_form', $data); e  $this->load->view('eventos_form', $data); ao mesmo tempo? é isso?

Comment: Isso @IsraelZebulon

Comment: mandei uma resposta para voce testar. Se der erro, envie-o aqui.

Comment: e ai? funcionou?

Comment: Sim @IsraelZebulon valeu!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na view eventos:

```
public function create() 
    {
        $data = array(
            'button' => 'Create',
            'action' => site_url('eventos/create_action'),
            'idEvento' => set_value('idEvento'),
            'nome_evento' => set_value('nome_evento'),
            'data_inicio' => set_value('data_inicio'),
           'data_fim' => set_value('data_fim'),
        );

        $data2 = array(
            'button' => 'Create',
            'action' => site_url('categorias_inscricao/create_action'),
            'idCategorias_Inscricao' =>      set_value('idCategorias_Inscricao'),
            'nome_categoria' => set_value('nome_categoria'),
            'descricao_categoria' => set_value('descricao_categoria'),
            'valor_categoria' => set_value('valor_categoria'),
           );
        $this->load->view('categorias_inscricao_form', $data2);
        $this->load->view('eventos_form', $data);

    }

 Tente chamar as views dessa forma.
```